# Why I got undefined variable when I dispatch gettAll data - ReactJs hooks redux Crud

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-hooks, crud, redux-thunk

I'm trying to print out data from my database. It's doing it all well by using hooks and without it so this time I tried to use redux and hooks to implement CRUD. But thats return an undefined every render. so I called the payload and it's an array of objects. I'm using redux, middleware Thunk and hooks. please can someone guide me to fix the issue.

here is the code bellow :

**Component.jsx**

```
import { retrieveCars } from '../action/cars.action'
    
     const cars = useSelector(state => state.cars);
        const dispatch = useDispatch();
      
        useEffect(() => {
          dispatch(retrieveCars());
          


        });
 <tbody>
                    {cars &&
                      cars.map((data) =>
                        <tr key={data.idCars}>
                       
                        <th scope="row">{data.idCars}</th>  
                      
                      <td>{data.carName}</td>
                      <td>{data.carModel}</td>
                      <td>
                      <Link to={"/classement/update/" + data.idCars}
                        className="btn btn-info"
                        >
                        Edit
                       </Link>
                
                      <button  className="btn btn-danger" onClick={() => deleteC(data.idCars)}>
                        Remove
                      </button>
                        </td> 
                     
                      
                     
                      </tr>
                    )
                    }
                      
                
                  </tbody>
```

**cars.action.js**

```
export const retrieveCars = () => async (dispatch) => {
    try {
      const res = await DataService.getAll();
  
      dispatch({
        type: RETRIEVE_CARS,
        payload: res.data,
      });
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
  };
```

**Car Reducer:**

```
const initialState = [];
  
  function carReducer(cars = initialState, action) {

    const { type, payload } = action;
  
    switch (type) {
      case CREATE_CAR:
        return [...cars, payload];
  
      case RETRIEVE_CARS:
        return payload;
}
```

**Store.js**

```
const initialState = {};

const middleware = [thunk];

const store = createStore(
  rootReducer,
  initialState,
  composeWithDevTools(applyMiddleware(...middleware))
);

export default store;
```

[image]

Comment: How did you create the store with reducer functions? Show the code

Comment: @slideshowp2 I added it to the question you can check it now

Comment: And how did you create the`rootReducer`?

Comment: @slideshowp2 import rootReducer from '../reducers/carReducer'; the car reducer is in the code above

Answer (score 1):

You should have a default case in your reducer.

```
  function carReducer(cars = initialState, action) {

    const { type, payload } = action;
  
    switch (type) {
      case CREATE_CAR:
        return [...cars, payload];
  
      case RETRIEVE_CARS:
        return payload;
       default:
    return cars;
    }
    }
```